# Ouput to a file and read it

Tags: ubuntu, cat, less

I am trying to output the `ps` command to a file in `/home/username/ps.txt`.  I want to create the file on the go, write the output of `ps` to it and also read the same in a single command.
I tried this:

```
ps > /home/username/ps.txt | less /home/username/ps.txt
```

It writes to the file after creating it but does not output it. But using `less` seperately gives proper output.

Could I perform this in a single command?

Comment: a *single* command? you already have two (ps, less). Smallest change IMHO is to change the pipe to a semicolon or `&&`

Comment: I meant in a single statement and yes changing to && worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tee` writes both to file and `stdout` , use that:

```
ps -ef | tee psoutput.txt | less
```

Or just use `&&` to open file with less upon successful completion of `ps`

```
ps -ef > psoutput.txt && less psoutput.txt
```

Comment: Why && ? Shouldnt piping have been the same thing?

Comment: So what you do in the example you have is `command > output.txt | another_command` . You cannot do that. The `stdout` of the command won't go to pipe, but to file. It only goes one way. That's why you want to redirect first, then open file , that's why `&&` , to know when command is finished.  Now, if you want to both redirect to file AND to pipe, use `tee` as I've shown

Answer (score 0):

Just too brief. `tee` can be used for this purpose

```
ps | tee ps-info.txt
```